# Using Python and pywin32 to automate data entry

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to write a python script that will take data and enter it into any form,

Here's my code so far:

```
def pasteNum(n):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT, str(n))
##CTRL-A
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LCONTROL,0x1d, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32api.VkKeyScan('A'),0x1e, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32api.VkKeyScan('A'),0x9e, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LCONTROL,0x9d, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
##CTRL-V
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LCONTROL,0x1d, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32api.VkKeyScan('V'),0xaf, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32api.VkKeyScan('V'),0x2f, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LCONTROL,0x9d, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    print "CTRL-V"
    time.sleep(.1)
```

The Ctrl-A part of the code works. However, it won't paste the data into notepad or any other text field that's in focus. Is there a better way to do this and what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).